# Undetectable webcam on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: camera

I have laptop Dell XPS 13 7390 with Ubuntu 19.10 on board.

And my webcam not detected on system. How can I fix the problem and start using the camera.

`dmesg | grep -i camera` command finds nothing

Found a [similar problem](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/XPS-13-9370-Ubuntu-16-04-webcam-not-detected/td-p/6087461) on version 16.04, it was solved by installing additional libraries, but for current version these libraries are missing